# Difference between glNormal3f and glNormalPointer

Tags: java, opengl, shader

i'm getting these strange two results when drawing with immediate mode and vertex arrays. In immediate mode i'm passing the normals by `glNormal3f`. My shader takes the normal and computes something like a shadow, but nothing seriously.

Immediate Mode:

```
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for (Triangle tri : this.triangles) {
        Vec3d normal = Vec3d.vectorProduct(
                Vec3d.sub(tri.getB(), tri.getA()),
                Vec3d.sub(tri.getC(), tri.getA())); //calculating normalvector
        glNormal3d(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);
        glColor3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        glVertex3d(tri.getA().x, tri.getA().y, tri.getA().z);
        glVertex3d(tri.getB().x, tri.getB().y, tri.getB().z);
        glVertex3d(tri.getC().x, tri.getC().y, tri.getC().z);
    }
    glEnd();
```

Result:

[image]

In the VAO variant, i'm storing the normals in a separate buffer, but calculated the same way:

```
for(Triangle tri : triangles) {

        Vec3d normal = Vec3d.vectorProduct(
                Vec3d.sub(tri.getB(), tri.getA()),
                Vec3d.sub(tri.getC(), tri.getA()));


        normals.put((float) normal.x);
        normals.put((float) normal.y);
        normals.put((float) normal.z);

    }

    normals.flip();

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glNormalPointer(4, normals);
    glVertexPointer(3,3*4, vertices);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, (vertices.capacity() / 3));

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
```

Result 2:

[image]

Obviously the normals get somehow mismatched but i can't find my mistake.

And the final question: What is the difference between glNormal3f and glNormalPointer considering the values passed to the shader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stride of your normal array is suspect. Why are you passing **4** for the stride to `glNormalPointer (...)`?

You are telling GL that there are 4-bytes (1 `float`) worth of space between each of your normals. However, `normals` is built in your code with 12-bytes between each successive normal. Incidentally, this is what you would call ***tightly packed*** and therefore passing **0** for the stride implies the same thing (4-bytes per-component x 3-components).

Your vertex array and normal array should actually have the same stride. `4*3` or simply **0**.

Comment: I was probably confused, is fixed. But now i'm getting an `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` Error...

Comment: @Matze: Did you remember to `flip (...)` the `vertices` buffer before calling `glVertexPointer (...)`? You may be overrunning the memory in your vertex array, I only see `normals` being flipped.

Comment: Yep, the vertices buffer gets flipped right after it gets filled. But it has to do with the normals - i don't get an exception if i comment the normals out.
The initialization of the normals buffer `normals = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(triangles.size() * 3);`

Comment: @Matze: Have you checked that `triangles.size () * 3` has the same value as `vertices.capacity ()`? Being that this is Java, you can usually get ***much*** more detailed exception information than what you've listed. I would suggest putting the call to `glDrawArrays (...)` in a try/catch block and then printing the callstack, etc. for the caught exception; `exception.printStackTrace (...)`.

Comment: vice versa, which size needs glDrawArrays? The specs says the number of Indices, but i doens't make a difference if i'm passing `(vertices.capacity() / 3) + (normals.capacity()  / 3)` or just `(vertices.capacity() / 3)` because both will give me the access violation

Comment: it isn't a java exception, it happens outside of the JVM in native code.

Comment: `glDrawArrays (...)` expects the total number of vertices to draw from your arrays. Each of your arrays should contain at least that many positions, colors, normals, texture coordinates, etc. In this case, I would even expect the two arrays to be exactly the same size.

Comment: But isn't it impossible to have the vertices and the normal buffer the same size? Three vertices define a Triangle, and one Triangle needs one normal, so the normals buffer size should be a third of the vertices buffers size

Comment: No, in GL each vertex stores a normal and a position. There is no way to tell GL to store normals per-triangle, you have to do it per-vertex. Usually the way people deal with this is by combining vertices with the same position and the normals for all triangles that have a vertex at that position are added together and then averaged. In fact, now that I think about this, I think this is your problem. You should be outputting ***3 normals per-triangle*** (the same normal 3 times, or the averaged normal as described above).

Comment: @Matze: Yes, if you change your loop a little bit so that it does `normals.put((float) normal.x);` `normals.put((float) normal.y);` `normals.put((float) normal.z);` 3 times in a row it should fix everything up. The reason you don't have to do this in the immediate mode version of your code is that it re-uses the old normal for each new vertex; behind the scenes each call to `glVertex3d (...)` is actually creating a ***new*** vertex, complete with its own copy of the *last* value you specified by calling `glNormal3d (...)`.

Comment: Good to know, thanks so far! But it's still somehow strange :D
I'm storing now the normal `xyz xyz xyz` and adjusted the size paramterer `2 * (vertices.capacity() / 3)` and somehow it still gets violated... both buffers are flipped

Comment: Actually, you are drawing 2x as many vertices as you are supposed to. The "size parameter" is supposed to be the number of vertices you want to draw. It is ***not*** related to how much data each vertex stores (*e.g.* position + normal), just the total number of vertices.

Comment: Finally it works, you saved my day! :) *looking on my watch* ok now the night :D I think i got it right now!